# Refreshing tokens on social tables API

Tags: social-tables

When I try to refresh my access token, I get this message:

> "The grant type is unauthorised for this client_id"

Do I need custom privileges to be able to refresh the access token?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using our API.

So... unfortunately even though you do get a refresh token back from the server when you get the initial authorization code, by default at this point we do not enable the refresh_token grant type for third party apps. We are working on this and I have created a ticket in our system to enable that.

In the mean time as a workaround you can repeat the initial Oauth flow to get a new Bearer token when the current one expires.  To your user this should be somewhat transparent as they will not have to give permission again to the app, it should just redirect them through that screen.

Sorry for any inconvenience this causes.  I will comment here when refresh tokens grants are being enabled for new apps.